# is it safe to use base64 encoding of mongdb object id in API endpoint?

Tags: mongodb, api, go, encoding, base64

Developing an API in Go with Mongodb as the database and would like to return a specific student in the database by it's ID specified in the URL (e.g. /students/5ed2176bc645348af0dc60d3). Would it be secure to use a base64 encoding of a mongodb object ID in the API endpoint? For example,

Given a document in the database `map[_id:ObjectID("5ed2176bc645348af0dc60d3") student:bob]`, encode "5ed2176bc645348af0dc60d3" with base64 standard encoding and then use this encoding as the URL. When someone hits the URL, decode it and then get the corresponding document by object id

Would there be any pros and cons to this or is there a better way not having to expose object IDs in the API endpoints?

Comment: Base64 is exactly as secure as plain text. If you don't mind sending your data in plain text, then Base64 is fine.

Answer (score 0):

base64 encoding can be trivially reversed. If someone decides to figure out how your API works, it will take them less than a minute to get the ids back.

Comment: any good strategies to not have to expose object IDs then in the API?

Comment: retrieve a document by some ID so i can display the info in that document at a specific url which contains that ID, was thinking i could use the object ID since it's already a unique id instead of generating a new one

Comment: You can, but what does this have to do with base64 encoding?

Comment: thought it'd be secure to encode it but u answered the question that it can be decoded, thanks, i guess i can just use the same object ID in the mongo document in my API endpoint url